# Yii2 insert partial data into table

Tags: mysql, yii2, sql-insert

I'm inserting into a table data coming from another table which is basically a subset of the first table.

```
 $partialProduct = partialProducts::find()
                 ->where(['company_id' => $company_id])
                 ->andWhere(['productName' => $productName])->one();

 $partialProductData = ($partialProductData['attributes']);

 $product = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                    ->insert('products', [
                        'field1' => $field1value,
                         ...
                         ...
                        'fieldN' => $fieldN,
                    ])->execute();
```

Something like that could work, but considering that partialProductData has a lot of fields, I was searching for a cleaner way of doing it.

I've tried with a `foreach(partialProductData as $key => $value)` approach, considering that the keys are named as the products table column names, but I struggled in obtain something viable.

Comment: Are the field names the same in both models? And do both models extend `\yii\db\ActiveRecord`?

Comment: The field name are the same in both models. The models extend BaseModel and not ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, creating an array of key/values pairs should work if the keys match the table fields in both models. Something like:

```
$data = [];
foreach($partialProduct->attributes as $key => $value):
  $data[$key] = $value;
endforeach;

$product = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
  ->insert('products', $data)
  ->execute();
```

Alternatively, you could use massive assignment. Again, for this to work the fields on both models would need to match:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->attributes = $partialProduct->attributes;
$product->save();
```

If you only want to save certain fields from your partialProducts to your Product, you can use [scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/852/optimize-scenarios-for-yii2) to select the specific fields you want to be to set with [massive assignment](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#massive-assignment):

In Product.php

```
const SCENARIO_TEST = 'test';

...

public function scenarios()
{
  return [
    self::SCENARIO_TEST => ['field_1', 'field_2'], // Any field not listed here will not be set
  ];
}
```

And wherever you're doing the save:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->scenario = Product::SCENARIO_TEST;
$product->attributes = $partialProduct->attributes;
$product->save();
```